# Android: multi select list preferences with autocomplete?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-preferences, multiautocompletetextview, android-multiselectlistpreference

I need to let the user in my app to choose several cities.

so the users should be able to choose "All Cities" or "multiple cities", every tap on city name will be shown above the list, and every click on the list above, will bring it back down, I designed a sketch so you will be able to understand what i need.
[image: autocomplete list]

the closest example i have found is android chips edit text:
https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips

but it works on contacts and actually its too much code for a pretty simple select list.

any idea?

Thank you!

Eran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I have found exactly what I was looking for, you can find it here:
https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultiSelectSpinner

Thank anyway.

Eran.

Answer (score 2):

There are many library in Github. You can find it here:

```
Multi Choice - Github Links
```

https://github.com/wongk/MultiSelectSpinner

https://github.com/GunaseelanArumaikkannu/MultiSpinner

https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultiSelectSpinner